# Division operation not giving the right result

Tags: c++17

i'm having a problem with this operation that is not really giving the right result.
The result is 60216 on terminal, but it should be 563376.

```
int a = 8536;
int b = 563376;
int d = 8536;
unsigned long long int k = (a*b);
cout << k/d << endl;
```

Comment: 32 bit integer overflow

Comment: it doesn't matter than k is `long`.  a and b are both `int` so it generates a signed 32 bit result and THEN assigns it to the long. Your long storage is too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need long long everywhere

```
long long int a = 8536;
long long int b = 563376;
long long int d = 8536;
unsigned long long int k = (a * b);
std::cout << k / d << std::endl;
```

note that its nothing to do with division. THis

```
int a = 8536;
 int b = 563376;
unsigned long long int k = (a * b);
std::cout << k  << std::endl;
```

gives the wrong answer too

Comment: I tryed to put only b as long long int and it worked. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Leonardo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Comment: @Leonardo summary: types get promoted to the longest one in a given operation. SO having one long long in a calculation promotes them all to long long

Comment: Oh, thanks! I Have spent so much time trying to fix that. You helped me a lot. Thanks again.